# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index, but such record doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have a C# based order fulfilment process that includes a step in importing orders into our Macola ERP. It has the following steps:

1. It figures out the next sequential order ID and confirms that it is indeed unique. For what it's worth, this is the SQL it uses:

```
DECLARE @ordNo char(8), @ordNoConfig char(8), @checkCount tinyint, @nextUseNum bigint, @nextConfigNum bigint
SELECT @ordNo = start_ord_no FROM oectlfil_sql WHERE oe_ctl_key_1 = 1
SELECT @nextConfigNum = CAST(@ordNo AS bigint) + 1
SELECT @ordNoConfig = STUFF('00000000', (9-LEN(CAST(@nextConfigNum AS varchar(8)))), LEN(CAST(@nextConfigNum AS varchar(8))), CAST(@nextConfigNum AS varchar(8)));
SELECT @checkCount = ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM oeordhdr_sql WHERE ord_no = @ordNo) + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM oehdrhst_sql WHERE ord_no = @ordNo))

WHILE (@checkCount > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @nextUseNum = CAST(@ordNo AS bigint) + 1
    SELECT @nextConfigNum = @nextUseNum + 1
    SELECT @ordNo = STUFF('00000000', (9-LEN(CAST(@nextUseNum AS varchar(8)))), LEN(CAST(@nextUseNum AS varchar(8))), CAST(@nextUseNum AS varchar(8)));
    SELECT @ordNoConfig = STUFF('00000000', (9-LEN(CAST(@nextConfigNum AS varchar(8)))), LEN(CAST(@nextConfigNum AS varchar(8))), CAST(@nextConfigNum AS varchar(8)));

    SELECT @checkCount = ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM oeordhdr_sql WHERE ord_no = @ordNo) + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM oehdrhst_sql WHERE ord_no = @ordNo))
END

UPDATE oectlfil_sql SET start_ord_no = @ordNoConfig WHERE oe_ctl_key_1 = 1
SELECT @ordNo";
```

2. It attempts to insert the data using that order ID.

On step two, it gets the error

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index".

The index includes the order ID.

However, when querying for the supposedly duplicate row, it does not exist. We've tried bumping up the order ID that's grabbed in Step 1 to see if skipping would help, but that produced the same result.

Our customer support team has a separate UI that they can use to enter orders manually, and they say they have been able to use that without issue. It's only our C# app that encounters it. We haven't changed the code recently.

The app does use Entity Framework.

We've tried running a database trace, but we aren't seeing any obvious issues with the results.

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue or what might be good to try? We thought about rebuilding the index, but there has been doubt that it will work.

Comment: Have you tried manually inserting a row using that ID to see if it still barks? If not then you are probably misidentifying the problem. And FWIW wouldn't an IDENTITY column make this a LOT easier?

Comment: `However, when querying for the supposedly duplicate row, it does not exist. ` if the EF app had attempted a second insert a transaction, and rolled back the first row would be gone.

Comment: And are you 100% sure your app is the *only* app that is calling your code at one time? Because if there is any chance it is called twice you could easily get concurrency issues.